# What advantages does implementing Serializable give you rather than a simple method?

Tags: java, serialization

I am a little confused on what advantages the Serializable interface does. 
I will explain my question a little further.

Let's say I have a class called Dog.

```
public class Dog {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Dog(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

So now I if I needed to convert that into a String, I could override the toString method and make it do something like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name + "=" + age;
}
```

or create a method that does that.

Now, what does implementing Serializable do different? Or what makes it better?

Thanks for the help,
BetaNyan.

Answer (score 0):

Serializable produces a binary format for saving/restoring the data. This is different from `toString()`, in that `toString()` is a human (text) format for debugging that isn't necesarily reversible (e.g. it may simply summarize the key information necessary for understanding what the item is, and there is no automatically generated code to convert the content back into the object). If you make your object serializable, you can read/write the object using Object([Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html)|[Output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html))Stream.

However, instead of Serializable, there are even better approaches to binary serialization that are interoperable with other languages and have a better story with respect to versioning. If you are looking into persisting / communicating data, take a look at [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/?hl=en) or [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/index.html).

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate it. Just another quick question, how would I utilize it? Like if I wanted to send a Dog variable to something, how would I go across doing that? (btw, I know how to send String, etc over connections)

Comment: Well, I wouldn't recommend doing it with Serializable, but with Serializable, you would layer an ObjectOutputStream on top of your connection and then write the data to the ObjectOutputStream. Using protocol buffers (my preferred solution), you would use the protocol buffer syntax to declare a "Dog" message, and you would use its auto-generated toByteArray(), toByteString(), or writeTo() methods to write obtain the binary-encoded format of the data and write it to a stream.

Comment: @BetaNyan no problem!

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

I suggest that you look at these for more information on serializing, but the main gist is that you can put an instance of an object into a file for later use. Meaning that any values and variables unique to a specific instance of an object will be saved in a file for future use.

Answer (score 0):

So, there are 2 things:

1. `toString()`

   `toString()` provides you with a way to print things the way you want them to. So, when someone tries to print your Dog class state, they would see something meaningful, rather than `ObjectName@Hashcode`
2. `Serializable`

   Serializable is a marker interface that has no methods to override, but allows you to save the state of your object on a disk. Say, you want to save your Dog object state on a drive and port it on a different network running on different OS, then you can safely decode the object state out of your drive using Serialization process.

`toString()` and `Serialization` are different concepts.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this was confusing me.